# Adding an extension method to an existing class in XText

Tags: eclipse, dsl, xtext

The XText documentation states that existing (Xbase) library classes can be extended. The exact text is:

> Languages extending Xbase might want to contribute to the feature scope. Besides that, one can of course change the whole implementation as it seems fit. There is a special hook, which can be used to add so-called extension methods to existing types.

I found an older [blog post](https://koehnlein.blogspot.de/2011/07/extending-xbase.html) that describes the mechanism for an earlier Xtext version, but the classes used in 'registering' the extension are marked deprecated in the xtext version that I am using (2.10). What is the current way of registering these extension methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the new place is `org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.scoping.batch.ImplicitlyImportedFeatures`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked into it and found [this](https://github.com/nolandpham/eclispe_smarthome/blob/605e54084ec869ad82b49d6da0f44cd4df82e716/bundles/model/org.eclipse.smarthome.model.script/src/org/eclipse/smarthome/model/script/scoping/ScriptImportSectionNamespaceScopeProvider.java). Is that a good example of the way it is supposed to be used now?

Comment: depends on that you exactly want to do. please elaborate. it it is just registering additional extensions classes ImplicitlyImportedFeatures.getExtensionClasses is the way to go